# Keep selected options in Vuetify multiple autocomplete with options from the database

Tags: autocomplete, vuetify.js

I'm trying to use Vuetify's Autocomplete component to select a list of users from the database, searching by name. I want to allow selecting multiple users, with each user appearing as another chip in the autocomplete's input field.

It works fine for the first user selected, but then if I start to type the name of another user, when the search results are updated in the autocomplete component, if the first selected user was not included in the new search results, that user disappears from selected chips.

Here's an example of what happens:

[image]

Is there a way to maintain the selected options even if they are no longer included in the search results from the database?

Answer (score 0):

So I found what I feel is an acceptable solution, though I'd love to know if there's a better one.

Basically instead of just overwriting the user search results with what I get from the database via api, I first append the selected results to the new search results. Something like this:

```
axios.get('/api/users/' + this.search)
  .then(res => {
    this.user.parents.forEach((id) => res.data.push(this.getSearchResultById(id)));
    this.parentOptions = res.data;
  });


getSearchResultById(id) {
  return this.parentOptions.find((parent) => parent.id === id);
},
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the props **cache-items** in your case. It keep the selected items in autocomplete viewable

Comment: `cache-items` prop keeps a local unique copy of all items that have been passed through the items prop. It does not play any role manipulating the selected values in the autocomplete